# Find all integer solutions to hyperbola.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conic-sections

The question is find all integer solutions to $6xy+4x-9y-7=0$

Now I did trial and error and found $(1,-1)$ to be an integer solution.

This question is in my summer math homework. We have not been taught about the behaviour of hyperbolas and only know what they look like. I do know some basic coordinate geometry, though. Is there a definitive way to approach this question? Any help, hint or a link to a similar question is highly appreciated. I couldn't find a similar question on MSE. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Change variables $x=a+b$ and $y=a-b$. Then complete the squares. Finally pass the two squares to one side and the constant term to the other, and factor the difference of squares. Equate those factors to possible factorizations of the constant term and solve the system of linear equations that gets formed. Collect the solutions of those systems that are integer.

Comment: Do you know any modular arithmetic? Try reducing the equation modulo various integers $m$,  and check the solutions there.

Comment: The equation is $(2x-3)(3y+2)=1$. There are a limited number of ways to factor $1$.

Comment: @robjohn Thanks a ton. Turn this into an answer. Mention only this one single line in your answer. I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** The equation is $(2x-3)(3y+2)=1$. There are a limited number of ways to factor $1$.

Comment: Thanks bro. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

$$2x=\dfrac{9y+7}{3y+2}=3+\dfrac1{3y+2}$$

So, $3y+2$ must divide $1$

$\implies3y+2=\pm1$